# How can I reduce the size of the 'FormDatepicker' from fluent ui in react-js project

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I used **FormDatepicker** from [fluent UI](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.66.2/components/form/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#usage-datepicker) in my react project. But this is the calendar they showed in the documentation [image]

But this is what I am getting when I use that component [image]

I want to reduce this extra space in the calender.

```
<FormDatepicker
 size='small'
 maxDate={toDate}
 onDateChange={fromDateChange}
 defaultSelectedDate={fromDate}
 inputOnly />
```